# Компонент Angular, отображаемый только при первом входе

Tags: node.js, angular, компоненты

При регистрации на сайте, пользователю на почту приходит письмо. Пользователь проходит по ссылке в письме и автоматически редиректиться на сайт, уже как залогиненый пользователь.И при таком редиректе он попадает на страницу, с советами для новичков.

Это описание работы сайта trello.com. Вот только после того как пользователь покинул эту страницу(https://trello.com/create-first-board), на нее больше никогда нельзя попасть.

Вопрос, как создать подобную (одноразовую) страницу в Angular 8? Какие техники можно использовать? (рабочий стэк node.js + angular).

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять переменную в cookies или localStorage. И по ней перенаправлять пользователей. Способ не работает если один и тот же пользователь заходит из разных браузеров.

Как вариант, можно хранить переменную на сервере.